# Make JSP unaccessible from outside

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP that gets opened by a Servlet, so I can forward a variable by doing this:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Page.jsp");
request.setAttribute("filesystem", getFileSystem());
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Without the "filesystem" variable the JSP would have no content except for the sidebar and header menu.

My Problem is, that the user is still able to call the JSP by entering `website.com/Page.jsp` into the browser.

Is there anyway to stop the user from doing this?

Comment: If you want to restrict a user from accessing a particular page, you should use session management

Comment: Put your JSPs inside WEB-INF

Comment: @MouadELFakir this seems to be the right answer to my problem =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can put `JSP` files at any location in the `WAR` file, however if we put it inside the `WEB-INF` directory, it will prevent users from access it directly from the external.

Then re-adapt your code to take these changes in consideration :

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Page.jsp");
//...
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your JSPs inside WEB-INF directory which is not accessible to users accessing from outside. Technically Servlet containers do not serve any content inside WEB-INF directory and hence our JSPs are safe from direct access.

Example:

```
   <servlet>
        <display-name>userdata</display-name>
        <servlet-name>userdata</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/userdata.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>userdata</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/userdata</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Note: Consider using frameworks like Struts, Spring which handles such minor things in a more convenient manner.