# Can i make a Java Servlet unaccessible from outside?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Similiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608022/make-jsp-unaccessible-from-outside), but I want a regular servlet to be only accessible through the RequestDispatcher.

For example, I have a servlet that is mapped to `/hiddenUrl`. This should happen:

```
//forwards successfully
request.getRequestDispatcher(contextPath + "/hiddenUrl").forward(request,response);

//404 not found
response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/hiddenUrl")
```

Just like a JSP that is moved inside `WEB-INF` directory. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry but this looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Can you explain what you want to achieve (this technology is not new, and others may already have easier solution to your *real* problem)?

Comment: @Pshemo I included a partial with <jsp:include page="mypartial.jsp" />   but now I need to perform some data retrieval before showing the partial. This means that now i need to do <jsp:include page="/urlPatternToServlet" /> which will address me to a servlet which returns mypartial.jsp. But i don't want "/urlPatternToServlet" to be accessible from the outside. There's no XY problem, i just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Did you try binding the servlet to `/WEB-INF/urlPatternToServlet`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz i was _really_ convinced that such mapping would have not worked and that localhost:8080/myapp/WEB-INF/urlPatternToServlet would've been still accessible. Instead, that's not true! The servlet now is not directly accessible. Thank you for your help (why not make it an actual answer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A servlet container will never directly serve a request starting with `/META-INF/` or `/WEB-INF/` (see [chapter 10.5 of the specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#directory-structure)):

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document root of the application. Most of the WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the application. Except for static resources and JSPs packaged in the META-INF/resources of a JAR file that resides in the WEB-INF/lib directory, no other files contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the container.

Therefore a servlet mapped to `/WEB-INF/something` will be visible to other servlets and JSPs, but not directly to the user.